# What does this means in this context ? コルセットがちょっと苦しい (A character said this after she ate too much foods ,because they tastes too good.)

Tags: meaning, expressions

I don't understand this part of a sentence: "**コルセットがちょっと苦しい**".

I can only make a wild guess based on the context : "My stomach might feel a bit uncomfortable" (?), but I'm not sure. Full sentence:

> ご馳走様でした。おじさまが用意してくれたお料理、とっても美味しかったからお腹いっぱい食べちゃって、**コルセットがちょっと苦しいかも**

Comment: Have you looked up コルセット?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They used the loanword "コルセット", so it most likely literally means "corset". Which means, the speaker is feeling uncomfortable due to wearing a corset and having eaten too much.